# sigma.js: can't display graph with json

Tags: javascript, json, sigma.js

I have difficulty display graph with json file. I have try to run the example(load-external-json.html) provide by the application but it can't display graph.
I look through the web for solution but haven't find one solution that solve my problem.

the plug-in use: plugins/sigma.parsers.json/sigma.parsers.json.js

```
sigma.parsers.json("data/arctic.json", // Here I need to put the filepath instead of "data.json"
{
container: document.getElementById('container'),
settings: {
  defaultNodeColor: '#00a',
  edgeColor: 'default',
  defaultEdgeColor: '#a00'
} });
```

Best Regards,
luis

Comment: do you check for js errors?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this plugin makes an XHR request to get the specified file (in this case `data/arctic.json`). That means you may need a run a server locally in order to see this work properly.

If you have Python installed, an easy way to do this is to run `python -m SimpleHTTPServer` from the directory where `load-external-json.html` is located. Then you should be able to see it live at `http://localhost:8000/load-external-json.html`.

Answer (score 0):

From sigma.js wiki on github:

> Sigma provides many code examples to show you what it can do and how to use it. Some of these examples load external data files, and you need to access them through a local server to see the examples working.

you need to run a simple Node based http server. Just follow the instructions on the wiki:

https://github.com/jacomyal/sigma.js/wiki